# Proving that holomorphic on $D \setminus \gamma$ and continuous on $D$ function is holomorphic on $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's consider an arbitrary region $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ and let $\gamma \in D$ be a smooth curve. I would like to prove that if $f$ is holomorphic in $D \setminus \gamma$ and continuous in $D$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $D$.

Probably, the idea of applying the Riemann's theorem on removable singularities might work (since we know that if $a \in D$, and $f$ is holomorphic on $D \setminus \{a\}$, then $f$ can be extended to a holomorphic function on $D$) but it still unclear how to make use of it (or maybe it's not as benefitial as it can be seen on the first glance).

Are there any hints that might help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual trick is to use Morera's theorem.

Comment: Can anyone give a bit more details?